# How can I install ‘Theme Selector’ GNOME Shell extension?

Tags: 11.10, gnome, extension

I have seen tutorials around the web to do it with 11.04 if you downloaded GNOME shell from the PPA, but I can't compile it because it gives me errors. I can't use a DEB package that is available for users like me that can't compile from git. I'm guessing it is because I've installed GNOME Shell from the Ubuntu Software Center after installing 11.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run the following in a terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/gnome3
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gnome-shell-extensions-user-theme
```